# Loading glide images in view pager layouts

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-glide

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I have this view pager class having three layouts. How can I insert drawable images in these layouts using glide?

I have tried doing it in the instantiateItem method but it does not work. Can anyone help me with this ? Thanks in advance.

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

```
public class ViewPage_Holder extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinearLayout Layout_bars;
    TextView[] bottomBars;
    int[] screens;
    Button Skip;
    ViewPager vp;
    MyViewPagerAdapter myvpAdapter;
    PreferenceManager preferenceManager;
    ImageView imageViewlogo;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_page__holder);

        vp = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        Layout_bars = findViewById(R.id.layoutBars);
        Skip = findViewById(R.id.Skip);
        imageViewlogo = findViewById(R.id.imageViewlogo);

        preferenceManager = new PreferenceManager(this);

        Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(R.drawable.gramworkx_final)
                .override(280, 100)
                .fitCenter()// scale to fill the ImageView and crop any extra
                .into(imageViewlogo);

        if (!preferenceManager.FirstLaunch()) {
            launchMain();
            finish();
        }
        screens = new int[]{
                R.layout.smart_farming_intro,
                R.layout.best_harvest_intro,
                R.layout.save_water_intro
        };
        ColoredBars(0);

        myvpAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter();
        vp.setAdapter(myvpAdapter);

        Skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                launchMain();
            }
        });

    }

    private void ColoredBars(int thisScreen) {
        int[] colorsInactive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.dot_on_page_not_active);
        int[] colorsActive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.dot_on_page_active);
        bottomBars = new TextView[screens.length];

        Layout_bars.removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0; i < bottomBars.length; i++) {
            bottomBars[i] = new TextView(this);
            bottomBars[i].setTextSize(40);
            bottomBars[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("¯"));
            Layout_bars.addView(bottomBars[i]);
            bottomBars[i].setTextColor(colorsInactive[thisScreen]);
        }
        if (bottomBars.length > 0)
            bottomBars[thisScreen].setTextColor(colorsActive[thisScreen]);
    }

    private int getItem(int i) {
        return vp.getCurrentItem() + i;
    }

    private void launchMain() {
        preferenceManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);

        startActivity(new Intent(ViewPage_Holder.this, SignIn.class));
        finish();
    }

    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            ColoredBars(position);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

        }
    };


    public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        public MyViewPagerAdapter() {
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(screens[position], container, false);

            ImageView imageView_sw = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_sw);
            ImageView imageViewbh = view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewbh);
            ImageView imageViewsf = view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewsf);

            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
            int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
            int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

            Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(R.drawable.save_water)
                    .override(width, height)
                    .fitCenter()// scale to fill the ImageView and crop any extra
                    .into(imageView_sw);

            Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(R.drawable.smartfarming)
                    .override(width, height)
                    .fitCenter()// scale to fill the ImageView and crop any extra
                    .into(imageViewsf);

            Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(R.drawable.farm_steps)
                    .override(width, height)
                    .centerCrop() // scale to fill the ImageView and crop any extra
                    .into(imageViewbh);

            container.addView(view);
            return view;
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return screens.length;
        }
        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            View v = (View) object;
            container.removeView(v);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject( View view, Object object) {
            return view == object;
        }
    }
}
```